# How can I surround a digit in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to change my list of digits that are separated by a space change to latex table syntax. How can I easy change this list:

```
1.1 2.2 3.3
```

to this one:

```
 \(1.1\) & \(2.2\) & \(3.3\) \\
```

I tired with substitute in vim but doesn't found a syntax for appending before a word. Is there some one how could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with macro. First move your cursor to the first `1` then:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>(</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>)</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>&</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>

to record the macro. Then press `x@q` to replay it `x` times.

Well this will leave a `&` at the end, just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two separate substitutes:

```
:s/\d\.\d/ \\(&\\) \&/g
:s/&$/\\\\
```

I would recommend reading through a regex tutorial, such as [vim-regex.com](http://vimregex.com/)

Comment: Is it possible that you mean :s/\&%/\\\\

Comment: @655e69cf802b31 No, definitely not. `\&` means something completely different, and `%` means a literal percent sign. `&$` means *an ampersand at the end of the line*